# Prevent multiple alert on "oninvalid" html

Tags: javascript, html

I was thinking, can i stop the alerts after the first?

I'll explain it better, every time I confirm the form, start an aler for every input that has oninvalid.

so if i have 10 inputs, i'll have 10 alarms. Is it possible to interrupt them after the first one?

```
<form>
  <input type="text" oninvalid="alert('test1')" required />
  <input type="text" oninvalid="alert('test2')" required />
  <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9d1L5pxd/1/

Comment: why not bind to some sort of function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider doing something like I demonstrate below. Basically just add an event handler to the send button, which will call a validation function on your form each time it's clicked.

The validation function checks all the text type field values. If a text field with an invalid value is encountered, the function will return `false` (stop immediately).

If the function doesn't find any problems with the user input then it will return `true`. You can use the return value to determine if the form should be submitted or whatever if you need to.

```js
var btnSend = document.getElementById('btnSend');
btnSend.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var isValid = validateForm();

  if (isValid)
    console.log('Form is ready to submit.');
});

function validateForm() {
  var formToValidate = document.getElementById('dataForm');
  var elements = formToValidate.elements;
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].type == 'text') {
      //replace this with your actual validation
      var invalid = elements[i].value.length == 0;

      if (invalid) {
        alert(elements[i].id + ' is invalid.');
        return false;
      }

    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

```html
<form id="dataForm">
  <input id="field1" type="text" required />
  <input id="field2" type="text" required />
  <input id="btnSend" type="button" value="Send">
</form>
```